# Recursively return all words from .txt file using attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I am fairly new to Haskell and I'm just starting to learn how to work with attoparsec for parsing huge chunks of english text from a .txt file. I know how to get the number of words in a .txt file without using attoparsec, but I'm kinda stuck with attoparsec. When I run my code below, on let's say

> "Hello World, I am Elliot Anderson. \nAnd I'm Mr.Robot.\n"

I only get back:

> World, I am Elliot Anderson. \nAnd I'm Mr.Robot.\n" (Prose {word =
>   "Hello"})

This is my current code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Exception (catch, SomeException)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Txt
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative ((<*>), (*>), (<$>), (<|>), pure)

{-
This is how I would usually get the length of the list of words in a .txt file normally.

countWords :: String -> Int
countWords input = sum $ map (length.words) (lines input)

-}

data Prose = Prose {
  word :: String
} deriving Show

prose :: Parser Prose
prose = do
  word <- many' $ letter
  return $ Prose word

main :: IO()
main = do
  input <- Txt.readFile "small.txt"
  print $ parse prose input
```

Also how can I get the integer count of words, later on? Furthermore any suggestions on how to get started with attoparsec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a pretty good start already - you can parse a word.
What you need next is a `Parser [Prose]`, which can be expressed by combining your `prose` parser with another one which consumes the "not prose" parts, using `sepBy` or `sepBy1`, which you can look up in the `Data.Attoparsec.Text` documentation.

From there, the easiest way to get the word count would be to simply get the length of your obtained `[Prose]`.

EDIT:
Here is a minimal working example. The `Parser` runner has been swapped for `parseOnly` to allow for residual input to be ignored, meaning that a trailing non-word won't make the parser go cray-cray.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Atto where

--import qualified Data.Text.IO as Txt
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Control.Applicative ((*>), (<$>), (<|>), pure)

import qualified Data.Text as T

data Prose = Prose {
  word :: String
} deriving Show

optional :: Parser a -> Parser ()
optional p = option () (try p *> pure ())

-- Modified to disallow empty words, switched to applicative style
prose :: Parser Prose
prose = Prose <$> many1' letter

separator :: Parser ()
separator = many1 (space <|> satisfy (inClass ",.'")) >> pure ()

wordParser :: String -> [Prose]
wordParser str = case parseOnly wp (T.pack str) of
    Left err -> error err
    Right x -> x
    where
        wp = optional separator *> prose `sepBy1` separator

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let input = "Hello World, I am Elliot Anderson. \nAnd I'm Mr.Robot.\n"
  let words = wordParser input
  print words
  print $ length words
```

The provided parser does not give the exact same result as `concatMap words . lines` since it also breaks words on `.,'`. Modifying this behaviour is left as a simple exercise.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please elaborate a bit ? or give an example? Because I have been looking at the documentation for "sepBy" and Im not sure how to apply it specifically in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track! You've written a parser (`prose`) which reads a single word: `many' letter` recognises a sequence of letters.

So now that you've figured out how to parse a single word, your job is to scale this up to parse a sequence of words separated by spaces. That's what [`sepBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:sepBy) does: `` p `sepBy` q `` runs the `p` parser repeatedly with the `q` parser interspersed.

So a parser for a sequence of words looks something like this (I've taken the liberty of renaming your `prose` to `word`):

```
word = many letter
phrase = word `sepBy` some space  -- "some" runs a parser one-or-more times

ghci> parseOnly phrase "wibble wobble wubble"  -- with -XOverloadedStrings
Right ["wibble","wobble","wubble"]
```

Now, `phrase`, being composed out of `letter` and `space`, will die on non-letter non-space characters such as `'` and `.`. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to fix that. (As a hint, you'll probably need to change `many letter` to `many (letter <|> ...)`, depending on how exactly you want it to behave on the various punctuation marks.)